In Mysql Query : After adding DATE() in Groupby taking more than 15 sec, otherwise 1sec
Here is the query, here al.activated_date column is having timestamp. I want to group by application.id, application_logs.activated date.
When i remove DATE(al.activated_date), query excution time is 1.2sec.
But when i use it, exceeds 15sec..
SELECT 
    a.id, a.description, DATE(al.activated_date) as activated_date, a.category, COUNT(a.id) as total
FROM 
    application_logs al
JOIN 
    applications a ON al.behavior_id = a.id
JOIN 
    users u ON al.manager_id = u.id 
WHERE
  u.year_id = 3
AND 
  u.shift_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16)
and u.is_active = 1
AND 
  a.system_id IN ("43","70","68","69","19","20","45","44","77","46","47","78","11","53","62","63","7","3","50","65","64","73","66","4","12","82","75","26","76","1","2","13","51","42","67","85","14","5","52","8","48","17","71","58","60","79","80","81","18","6","21","22","55","83","23","84","24","25","56","9","27","28","31","29","32","33","34","10","35","36","15","37","38","39","59","40","41","72","16")
AND   
  a.id IN (4500+ ids)
AND 
  DATE(al.activated_date) >= "2024-07-31"
AND 
  DATE(al.activated_date) <= "2025-05-30"
AND 
  a.category in ('aa','bb')
GROUP BY 
  a.id, DATE(al.activated_date);


Please review my query, and kindly share some suggestion or ideas to achieve the same response.

Make it a habit to use standard single quotes for strings: system_id IN ('43','70', ...). And use standard date literals: DATE(al.activated_date) >= DATE '2024-07-31'. Also don't invoke functions on columns when avoidable. Instead of using AND DATE(al.activated_date) ... use AND al.activated_date >= DATE '2024-07-31' and al.activated_date < DATE '2025-05-31'.

@ThorstenKettner - (The DATE in DATE '2024...' is unnecessary but harmless.)

Please provide EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ... If ANALYZE is not available, provide EXPLAIN SELECT ....)

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE.

@Rick James: DATE '2024-07-31' is a date literal, while '2024-07-31' is a string literal. But you are right; as far as I know MySQL does not do the conversion at run time, but at parse time, and it guarantees that a string in '2024-07-31' format will get correctly converted into a date, so it doesn't make a difference. It is still a good habit to use proper date literals right away.

When you call a function on an column, the column index can't be used, so it slows down queries. Instead of filtering using the index, it has to scan all the rows, call the function, and then do the comparison.
Instead of converting the timestamp to a date, just compare with the appropriate times of day.
AND al.activated_date BETWEEN '2024-07-31 00:00:00' AND '2025-05-30 23:59:59'


Not just a function, but a different table.

Different from what?

applications.id, applications_logs...  This eliminates any chance of theGROUP BY` using an index.  (See title)

I was thinking of the WHERE clause, not GROUP BY.

This seems only natural:

With the ID the DBMS just have to count all its rows.
With the DATE(al.activated_date) added the DBMS will have to take every row, invoke the DATEfunction on the timestamp, and then sort all the resulting dates to get the aggregation groups. That may take a while.

If you want to speed this up, you should store the date as a computed value with the timestamp and then index it.
ALTER TABLE application_logs
  ADD COLUMN onlydate DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DATE(activated_date)) STORED;

CREATE INDEX idx ON application_logs (onlydate);

Then use it thus:
AND 
  al.onlydate >= DATE '2024-07-31'
AND 
  al.onlydate <  DATE '2025-05-31'
AND 
  a.category in ('aa','bb')
GROUP BY 
  a.id, al.onlydate;


Yes, and in MySQL 8.0 and later, you can create a functional index without adding a generated column.

We don't yet know whether it is datatype DATE, DATETIME, DATATIME(6), TIMESTAMP, etc.

@Rick James: I assumed TIMESTAMP from "al.activated_date column is having timestamp". And would it even make a difference, if it were a DATETIME instead?

The function call in DATE(al.activated_date) is unnecessary if the column is DATE.  Furthermore, it is not sargable, so it will run slower.

@Rick James: Yes, but it is very unlikely to be a DATE when they talk of a timestanp and even invoke the DATE function on it. I think we can safely assume that it is a TIMESTAMP or at least a DATETIME.

As Thorsten suggested, indexing is the best way way to tackle your problem. However, if still uncertain, you can go with subquerying it as well. The DATE() function in the GROUP BY clause forces the database to apply the function to each row in the application_logs table, resulting a full table scan. This is taking time in your case.
Something like below should optimize your query a bit:


SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.description, 
    sub.activated_date, 
    a.category, 
    COUNT(a.id) as total
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         al.behavior_id, 
         DATE(al.activated_date) as activated_date
     FROM 
         application_logs al
     WHERE 
         DATE(al.activated_date) >= '2024-07-31'
         AND DATE(al.activated_date) <= '2025-05-30'
    ) sub
JOIN 
    applications a ON sub.behavior_id = a.id
JOIN 
    users u ON al.manager_id = u.id 
WHERE
    u.year_id = 3
    AND u.shift_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16)
    AND u.is_active = 1
    AND a.system_id IN ("43","70","68","69","19","20","45","44","77","46","47","78","11","53","62","63","7","3","50","65","64","73","66","4","12","82","75","26","76","1","2","13","51","42","67","85","14","5","52","8","48","17","71","58","60","79","80","81","18","6","21","22","55","83","23","84","24","25","56","9","27","28","31","29","32","33","34","10","35","36","15","37","38","39","59","40","41","72","16")
    AND a.id IN (4500+ ids)
    AND a.category in ('aa','bb')
GROUP BY 
    a.id, sub.activated_date;



I would still suggest to go with indexing only. Cheers and good luck!
